# HDD only works a few hours after boot/reboot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, reboot

1 of the 3 HDDs (Western Digitial WD3003FZEX Black 3TB SATA 6GB/S 7200RPM 64MB Cache 3.5IN Hard Drive) fails in a RAID 0 array. At first, it disappears from the OS. Then, it re-appears after re-plug the cables, but not stable.

It works a few hours after boot/reboot, mdadm can read out the serial number, and ddrescue reads about 90GB data out at an average speed of 2 MB/s. After the problem appears, serial number becomes empty, and ddrescue reads 0 byte without any successful read.

```
I/O Controller : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2 (SATA)
          Port2 : /dev/sdd (WD-WMC5D0D9X6D8)
          Port3 : /dev/sde (WD-WMC1F0EARDW0)
          Port1 : /dev/sdc ()
```

Smart info when normal

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   138   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   143   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4966
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       236
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   194   194   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       179
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   051   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       35906
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       213
 16 Unknown_Attribute       0x0022   149   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       2633891565010
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       130
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       107
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   119   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   113   113   000    Old_age   Always       -       87
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   197   196   000    Old_age   Always       -       1765
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

The motherboard is ASUS X99-E USB 3.1, the RAID 0 is setup with Intel RST, and the I/O Controller is still left in RAID mode in BIOS. However, the raid array only consists of WD-WMC5D0D9X6D8 and WD-WMC1F0EARDW0 in BIOS now, the broken is now a non-member drive. The system must somehow detect the drive failure and remove it from the array automatically.

I would like to clone the failing drive. Shall I keep rebooting the machine? Is there any command I can just reboot/reset the HDD rather than the whole system? Any other workaround? Thank you.

Comment: What do the SMART stats say about the drive health?

Comment: replace the data cable.

Comment: @FrankThomas See above.

Comment: @Moab It does not help.

Comment: your SMART stats look ok, but you do have one current pending sector. I'd run a disk check in thorough-mode, and check for bad sectors. this will reallocate the current pending sector, but it may discover more on the way.  if it does, its time to replace the disk. bad sectors tend to increase exponentially to time, so once you have more than a few, its time to back up and move on.